# is there a smarter way to combine markers and polygons

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm pretty new in using OpenStreetMaps with leaflet and got stuck trying to find out if there is a smarter way to include a boundary that I found on a map with markers that I created.

The best way I found until now is to find the area I need to show behind my markers ( for example this area : https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3123501#map=9/54.1375/-1.3898 ) and convert that to a list of lat/long coordinates that I add using (shortened the poly coordinates) code like this:

```
var latlngs = [
        [54.1508316, -2.5609075],
        [54.1498313, -2.5577575],
        ];
        var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {color: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 1.00)'}).addTo(map);
        // zoom the map to the polygon
        map.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds());
```

It produces the output I want but having 10k coordinates does not seem like an effective way to do this. Unfortunately my google and reading afforts dit not help me (yet) so I'm asking if somebody can point me in the right direction (if there is any) to do this in a smarter way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you're trying to do? What does it mean when you say you are finding the area you need and converting to lat/lons? What is the format you receive it in? If it is GeoJSON, you can use a GeoJSON layer directly without converting to a Leaflet Polygon.

Comment: Hi, I use the relation ID from the previously mentioned link and put it into this site : <http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/>. Then I downloaded the poly file and adjusted it in excel to format it into the coordinates as in my example code. So I really don't have a format to start with, just an ID and go from there.

Comment: Regarding performance: Leaflet's Polygon has a `smoothFactor` option (inherited from Polyline) to simplify the geometry depending on the zoom level. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip about smoothFactor I will keep that in mind. But performance is not an issue right now. It's mainly trying to find a better way then adding thousands of coordinates. But every time somebody give me a clue I try to google my way towards a solution. If I find something I will post it off course.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the info to try what @rfestag suggested. Using the GeoJSON from this link : <http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id=3123501&params=0> in my code using this https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/ looks like it's bringing me closer. Now I'm only trying to figure out the right syntaxt.

Comment: Did you figure this out? You should be able to swap out your assignment to `polygon` with something like this: `var polygon = L.geoJSON(geojson, () => ({color: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 1.00)'})).addTo(map);`

Comment: Hi, sorry but I have not managed to get it to work yet. What I'm not understanding is how to inlcude the relation (for example from this https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/88079 ) data into this function. My answer took some time because i've been trying to find an answer Googling but no luck yet. Only empty pages ;-)